# loop through controls on tabitem

Tags: c#, wpf, tabitem

How can I loop through controls on a `TabItem`?

Somehow, I can't find the control collection of the `TabItem`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx):

```
// Enumerate all the descendants of the visual object.
static public void EnumVisual(Visual myVisual)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
    {
        // Retrieve child visual at specified index value.
        Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);

        // Do processing of the child visual object.

        // Enumerate children of the child visual object.
        EnumVisual(childVisual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TabItem contains one control in property Content.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean loop in TabItem of TabControl :

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Background, Dispatcher);
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    private int _selectedItem = 0;
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl.SelectedItem = tabControl.Items[_selectedItem];
        _selectedItem = (_selectedItem + 1) % tabControl.Items.Count;
    }
```